# Is it possible to personalize content via Xamarin SDK or SSC using rules?

Tags: sitecore-services-client, rules-engine, xamarin

I was looking into Xamarin SDK and Creating a SSC to provide data to a Xamarin App, but I was wondering ... Is there a way to personalize data shown in Xamarin(or any Mobile App for that matter) based on rules defined on Sitecore?

For example, Let´s say that I just want to show a specific content item to a specific region, Is there a way to return to get that information from Xamarin SDK or via SSC? I guess that my question should be, can I get all rules defined for a content item?